# Difficulty with the openai_ros turtlebot2 tutorial when using noetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and i have been working through the TurtleBot2 with openai_ros tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/openai_ros/TurtleBot2%20with%20openai_ros).

When i get up to training the script (step 2) and run :`$ roslaunch my_turtlebot2_training start_training.launch`. I get the errors:

```
"No link elements found in urdf file"

 "Failed to load nodelet [/cmd_vel_mux] of type [yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet] even after refreshing the cache: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist."
```

After getting this error i then tried to install the `yocs_cmd_vel_mux` package however, this package does not appear to be available for Noetic. Do i need to use another version of ROS that does have the `yocs_cmd_vel_mux` package (melodic and kinetic) or is there another solution?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit and Noetic.

I hope i have provided enough information.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377082/difficulty-with-the-openai_ros-turtlebot2-tutorial-when-using-noetic/) by [JorgeMuehlebach](https://answers.ros.org/users/73783/jorgemuehlebach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-04-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hedwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/86750/hedwin/) on 2023-06-04**:
Hi, I have the same problem for the same tutorial. I'm also using noetic on ubuntu 20.04. I tried to install the repo from git https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_ocs . But (probably because this repository have no compatible branch with noetic), I wasn't able to catkin_make it. I had to install git@github.com:ros-perception/ar_track_alvar.git , to get the required package, and then catkin_make give me a lot of errors (I can't even copy the stack track because I have so much errors than it don't fit in my terminal).

Is there is a way to execute the launch file given in this tutorial using ros noetic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yocs_cmd_vel_mux is not installed. It is not release for noetic, you can put this repo. https://github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_ocs in your /src and catkin_make it.

---

Originally posted by [hengrobert](https://answers.ros.org/users/94660/hengrobert/) with karma: 16 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hedwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/86750/hedwin/) on 2023-06-05**:
Hi, This repository is not available for noetic and make it leads to other issues.